# Where exactly do the $0 and $1 properties come from when calling reduce on a string?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

The book Swift Coding Challenges has the following problem:

"Write a function that accepts a string, and returns how many times a specific character appears, taking case into account."

In one of the solutions

```
func challenge5b(input: String, count: Character) -> Int {
    return input.reduce(0) {
        $1 == count ? $0 + 1 : $0
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me where`$0` and `$1` come from. How exactly does the reduce function work when stepping through the input string?

Comment: See _Shorthand Argument Names_ section in [Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID95).

Comment: It is equivalent to `return input.reduce(0) { result, character in character == count ? result + 1 : result }`. As an aside, I think the choice of `count` for that second parameter name is not a very good choice.